# How to use dependent source in Proteus?

Tags: voltage, resistors, current-source, proteus

I am trying to determine the voltage at `v1`, `v2` and `v3` in a circuit like below using Proteus. The problem is that Proteus returns the wrong answer.

[image]

[image]

The circuit in Proteus returns `v1 = 32`, `v2 = 0` and `v3 = 45.333`, but the answer is `v1 = 32`, `v2 = -25.6` and `v3 = 62.4`.

The devices which I am using are: `CSOURCE`, `CCCS`, and `MINRES100K`. I also realize that if I change the `MINRES100K` to `RES` (which has the description is: generic resistor symbol), the result becomes: `v1 = 27`, `v2 = 0` and `v3 = 42`.

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try amending your circuit as per this: -

[image]

In microcap, I get the right answer: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]
hope the circuit made on proteus helps someone